# Как остановиться на точке при запуске проги из командной строки?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gdb

Как в коде остановитсья на точке останова, запуская прогу через коммандную строку в терминале MSVC?? Дело в том что передаю параметры при запуске и хочется уже с ними остановится в main

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6121299/14775762

Comment: Отладчик Visual Studio не поддерживает отладку исполняемых файлов, собранных gdb. А вообще-то у меня есть предположение, что в вопросе идет речь о Visual Studio Code. Указывайте аргументы в настройках запуска.

Comment: Что значит "в терминале MSVC"? В гуи Visual Studio не вариант отладиться?

Comment: Возможно.... надо знать какой именно отладчик, и попробовать его запустить указав нужный модуль в командной строке.

Comment: Можно попробовать "хитрый" вариант - создать нить, внутри нити вызвать исключение, на исключение вывалится окно с приглашением в отладчик-по-умолчанию, в отладчике проигнорировать исключение и продолжить отладку. Сам не пробовал.

Comment: А разве в студии нельзя задать параметры командной строки запускаемого приложения в настройках проекта?

Comment: @maestro да, так и сделал. Просто подумал есть ли способ через командную в терминале

Comment: @user7860670 описался, имел ввиду конечно же студию MSVS

Comment: Вопрос можно отредактировать нажав на кнопку Править под вопросом. Ну а вообще его можно закрывать, так как, как уже писалось выше, MSVS не поддерживает отладку gdb.